# Mocking a method of controller class when testing the web layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I have a controller class `ABCController.java`. I am writing a Web Layer testcase for the class.

```java
    @WebMvcTest(controllers = ABCController.class)
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class ABCControllerIntegrationTest {
        @Autowired
        private MockMvc mockMvc;


        @Test
        public void testSuccessfulCall(){
            mockMvc.perform(get("/pgdDataUrlGet"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
        }
    }
```

There is a function in my `ABCController.class generateSuccessCallEmail()`. I do not want this function to be called while running the testcase ?

I want to do something like this:

```java
doNothing.when(controllerObject).generateSuccessCallEmail(anyString);
```

Can anyone please help me with the right way of doing this ? The problem is that the Controller is getting loaded by using annotation `@WebMvcTest`. So how do I mock a function inside controller class ?

Comment: You will need to specify what your controller looks like exactly for us to help you better

Comment: You cannot change the behavior (definition) of the method while executing a test case .. although you can mock the existing behavior. If your ABCController.class generateSuccessCallEmail() returns a string mock with a string value anyways mock method won't execute your real behavior.

Comment: I do not want that method to execute while running testcase because it will send an email to a group of people. This the reason I want to mock that method and doNothing when it is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

- extract your method to another bean (`EmailService`)
- inject `EmailService` to your controller
- use `emailService.generateSuccessCallEmail()` method from the service bean in the controller.

On the test side, add

```
@MockBean
EmailService emailService;
```

and mock methods on this object.